# Creating User ID input page (Django/Python)

Tags: python, django

I would like to create a single page where the user inputs their ID or name. So the type would be text. Hitting submit would take them to a new page or the same one if they didn't enter anything. This isn't a log-in or authentication but just an input from the user, an identification. I need to know their ID for a poll. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: How do I store a text input from a user is what I'm asking? Everything I've found is about logging in.

Answer (score 0):

1 make a form

```
<form method="POST"><input name="user_id"/></form >
```

2 in your view you get the data and compare it

```
 def my_view(request):
     user_id = request.POST['user_id']
     return HttpResponse(User.get(user_id=user_id))
```

Comment: I get the error: 'Key 'user_id' not found in <QueryDict: {}' running that

Comment: either you dont have a User module or you have no users with the id you entered. ..  you can put it in a try:except to handle those cases

Comment: I fixed it but now it's telling me that User is not defined. Do I need to create a User module?

Comment: you need a User model class  ... this assumes you have some basic idea of how django sites work... go over and do the django tutorial at the django site...

Comment: thanks (+1) I forget sometimes ... (dont use too much django)